# Как отделить строку от символов - C#

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Вход:
"first@second.com"
Выход:
"second"

Нужно отделить строку (Вход) от двух символов ('@' и '.') и все, что находится за ними.
Как это лучше осуществить?

Comment: Что лучше чего? Где то,  что вы сравниваете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `String.Split()`.

```
string value =  "first@second.com";
string[] separators = {"@", "."};
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Можно и так. Но вы проделали только часть работы, дальше же нужно в массиве найти нужный элемент, а его вы будете определять по номеру индекса, который придется жестко в виде константы указывать прямо в коде, не так ли? Мне представляется вариант @andreycha лучше.

Comment: @Bulson Если автор парсит е-майлы, то почему бы и не зашить в константу ? Зато насколько короче и красивее код.

Comment: да, вы правы, простите за занудство :)

Comment: @Bulson: Не совсем занудство. А вдруг домен третьего уровня, и в имени содержится точка — как находить нужный кусок?

Comment: @VladD я про это даже и не подумал :) Придрался потому, что на чисто интуитивном уровне не люблю, когда в коде начинают появляться константы, в особенности, если это индексы для массивов или коллекций.

Answer (score 2):

Находите индексы двух символов, проверяете их, выкусываете нужную подстроку:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    var atIndex = input.IndexOf('@');
    var dotIndex = input.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (atIndex > -1 && dotIndex >= atIndex)
    {
        var output = input.Substring(atIndex + 1, dotIndex - atIndex - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: А если на входе будет следующее: "name.surname@second.th"

Comment: @knih91 хорошее замечание. Тогда для точно нужно использовать `LastIndexOf()`. Поправил ответ.

Comment: наверное лучше искать первую точку после @ а не просто последнюю точку. Хотя неизвестно, что нужно будет автору.

Comment: @Grundy а что если "name.surname@subdomain.second.th"? Автор в вопросе не очень ясно обозначил, чего именно он хочет и что у него за строки, поэтому дальнейшие модификации остаются за ним.